# Request attribute information from multiple polygons below a point

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, attribute-table

In QGIS I created a "grid" with points 100 m apart from each other. Below this layer of points there are multiple layers of polygons. Each polygon has a column with values in its attribute table. Is there a way to transfer the colum of each polygon into an attribute table of a point lying above the polygons?

In other words: Can a point "scan" the polygons that lie below and thus "read" and save the attributes they provide?

Comment: Answer: Depends on the software you're working with.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Yes, this can work, but if the centroid isn't within the largest polygon in the area, it won't get the "right" value, and if it's on a boundary you might get the last matched row (or no matches, depending of software and query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributesbylocation) for each polygon layer using the output of each as input to the next. Either manually or using a model:

[image]